# How to set a css property (background-color) dynamically in React?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, loops, jsx

I have a slideshow based on an array of objects with its characteristics, one of them is the `background-color` of the current slide. I have a property called `bg` which stores it. This is what I am using to set each background-color, which changes to every image, however I am using an `inline style` to do that.

I'd like to know if there is a way to do that without using this inline style?

Here is a sample of my code:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Fragment } from 'react'

import classes from './MainPageHeader.module.css'

const MainPageHeader = props => {

    let [minorSlideImg, setMinorSlideImg] = React.useState(0)

    let minorSlides = [
        {
            img: require('../../../assets/images/Header/MinorSlider/imgSolo1-mainpage.png'),
            alt: 'Produto 1',
            linkText: ['PRODUTO 5', '$ 19.99'],
            productId: 5,
            bg: 'rgb(151, 105, 105)'
        },
        {
            img: require('../../../assets/images/Header/MinorSlider/imgSolo2-mainpage.png'),
            alt: 'Produto 2',
            linkText: ['PRODUTO 13', '$ 199.99'],
            productId: 13,
            bg: '#fad3e0'
        },
        {
            img: require('../../../assets/images/Header/MinorSlider/imgSolo3-mainpage.png'),
            alt: 'Produto 3',
            linkText: ['PRODUTO 10', '$ 499.99'],
            productId: 10,
            bg: '#ccc'
        },
        {
            img: require('../../../assets/images/Header/MinorSlider/imgSolo4-mainpage.png'),
            alt: 'Produto 4',
            linkText: ['PRODUTO 11', '$ 999.99'],
            productId: 11,
            bg: 'rgb(238, 225, 183)'
        },
    ]
    
    const passSlideHandler = () => {
        if (minorSlideImg < minorSlides.length - 1) {
            setMinorSlideImg(minorSlideImg + 1)
        } else {
            setMinorSlideImg(0)
        }
    }   
    
    React.useEffect(() => {
        const interval = setTimeout(() => {
            passSlideHandler()
        }, 5000);
        return () => clearTimeout(interval);
    });    


    return (
        <Fragment>
            <div 
                className={classes.MinorSlider_subContainer} 
                style={{backgroundColor: minorSlides[minorSlideImg].bg}} // <= This is what I'd like to remove
            >
                <img 
                    src={minorSlides[minorSlideImg].img}
                    alt={"img-1"} 
                />
            </div>
        </Fragment>
    )
}

export default MainPageHeader
```

CSS:

```
.MinorSlider_subContainer {
    height: 65%;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: #ccc;
}

.MinorSlider_subContainer img {
    max-width: 100%;
}

.MinorSlider_subContainer div {
    position: relative;
    background-color: white;
    width: 100%;
    height: 65px;
}

.MinorSlider_subContainer div > *{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-evenly;

    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding-left: 25px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.MinorSlider_subContainer div p {
    margin: 0;
    color: rgb(75, 75, 75);
}
```

As can be seen, every five seconds the index of `minorSlides` changes, therefore, the slide that is being shown changes as well. This index is used to refer to each feature of the current slide.

So, is there a way to remove this inline style and make my JSX cleaner?

If I was using HTML, CSS and JS I could do that with JQuery or even plain JS, but I don't know how to do that here. I know I could create the element with a loop, but I'd like to keep changing only the index and not the whole element.

Here is the sildeshow:

[image]

Comment: Could you share a picture or short video of your current output?

Comment: @Rojo I inserted a GIF. I changed the interval to 1500 to make the GIF shorter.

Comment: So what is the problem with using `inline`?

Comment: No problem. I'd just like to make the JSX cleaner.

Comment: If you want to remove the inline style you can create a css class for every color, and instead of setting the style you can set the className value, or are you getting this data dynamically?

Comment: @lissettdm I thought about that, but as I said, I need the colors to be stored in the object, since it could be any color and not just a preset.

Comment: @Berg_Durden see my answer, it is an option

Answer (score 2):

If you can't create a css class for every color, the other option is to add the `style` tag and override the `background-color` property:

```
const subcontainerBackground = `.${classes.MinorSlider_subContainer} { background-color: ${minorSlides[minorSlideImg].bg}}`
        
return {(
   <Fragment>
      <style>
        {subcontainerBackground}
      </style>
      <div className={classes.MinorSlider_subContainer} >
         //....
      </div>
    </Fragment>
}
```

**EDIT**

Also you can add the style tag using [Document.createElement()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement):

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const content = `.${classes.MinorSlider_subContainer} { background-color: ${minorSlides[minorSlideImg].bg}}`;
    const style = document.createElement("style");
    style.innerHTML = content;
    document.head.appendChild(style);

    return () => document.head.removeChild(style);
  }, [minorSlideImg]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well it should be alright to use inline styling in this case.

Additionally you can do something like:

```
{
  ...
  bgClass: 'red'
}
```

add that class to the div element:

```
<div className={`classes.MinorSlider_subContainer ${minorSlides[minorSlideImg].bgClass}`} />
```

and style it in the end:

```
.red {
  background: 'red';
}
```

Or you can try to use reference

```
const ref = useRef()

useEffect(() => {
  if (ref.current == null) {
    return
  }

  ref.current.style.backgroundColor = minorSlides[minorSlideImg].bg
}, [minorSlideImg, ref])

<div ref={ref} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solutions for the same. Except, I add the colours in a list and use the rand function.

Here is the colour list

```
 const color_list = [
    "tomato",
    "blueviolet",
    "cornflowerblue",
    "indianred",
    "MediumAquaMarine",
    "MediumPurple",
    "Rebeccapurple",
    "sandybrown",
    "seagreen",
    "palevioletred",
    "lightsteelblue",
    "Gold",
    "teal",
  ];
```

I create a variable and add random function to it, to select a bunch of colours.

```
const rando_color = color_list[Math.floor(Math.random() * color_list.length)];
```

Simply pass the variable in the style option in the html div tag to dynamically assign background color

```
<div
   p={4}
   style={{
   backgroundColor: rando_color, // Added variable here 
   fontFamily: "Oswald",
   border: "solid 2px white",
   }}
   >
<h1>Some Content</h1>
  </div>
```

To make it simple, just add the variable directly in the tag without any curly braces. Also you could try using this variable in a react state for better loading. Add a default prop as well.